# Getting server used during FindAndModify

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

We have started upgrading our Mongo Java drivers from 2.x to 3.x. One important piece of information that we log during all commands is the server used so that we can easily identify any performance issues.

Previously, we could use getLastError to get some information about the server used (despite possibly being inaccurate).

We don't really want to duplicate all the internal FindAndModify logic since it has a lot of built in functionality with regards to picking the correct modify command, building the complex query, etc. Is there any other way to get the server used after a FindAndModify command?

Comment: Can you share a sample of affected code ? Do you run the `getLastError` after `findAndModify` command ?

Comment: getLastError is removed in version 3.x - however in 2.x, yes we did run getLastError after findAndModify.